# Angular Filter for Splice

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-filters

Here's [**Plunker Link**](http://plnkr.co/edit/si65sIdAiBmucIGuKP7v?p=preview)

How can i achieve slice with filter in angular ? I want only last 5 characters from string .It's pretty easy with slice(-5). But is there any way we can make filter out of it ?

js

```
  var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 var name = '36778882323';
 $scope.lastfive = name.slice(-5);
 });
app.filter('slice', function() {
 return function(arr,start, end) {
return arr.slice(start, end);
};
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `{{ name | limitTo:-5 }}`

See http://plnkr.co/edit/1EHMZCbxrksK94FUlVEs?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you made `name` a var and not within scope you needed something like.

```
$scope.name = '36778882323';
$scope.lastfive = $scope.name.slice(-5);
```

Then you're able to access it

```
{{name| slice:-5}}
```

Also `filters` is a module that is injected and custom filters are added to it

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['filters']);

angular.module('filters', [])
   .filter('slice', function() {
. . .
```

**Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/37pY03Va1nLe2E87yZOr?p=preview)**